# Why is text output from one CmdLet formatted and text output from another is not?

Tags: powershell, formatting, powershell-5.0, powershell-cmdlet

I have written 2 cmdlets, for converting between GUIDs and Oracle's Guid equivalent, the strings it displays for RAW columns used to store GUIDs. The first, `Convert-GuidToRaw`, accepts a GUID string param and outputs a raw string:

```
var raw = GuidConverter.Core.GuidConverter.ToRaw(Input);
WriteObject(raw);
```

Where `raw` has type `string`. When I run this cmdlet, I get a plain and simple string output:

```
PS D:\SANRAL\NRA2> New-Guid | Convert-GuidToRaw                                                                  
DD8386EE09231A43B7731880CCAD6B87
PS D:\SANRAL\NRA2>
```

My other cmdlet, `Convert-RawToGuid`, accepts a RAW string param representing a GUID and outputs a raw GUID:

```
var guid = GuidConverter.Core.GuidConverter.FromRaw(Input);
WriteObject(guid);
```

Where `guid` has type `Guid`. When I run this cmdlet, I get output formatted like a table:

```
PS D:\SANRAL\NRA2> Convert-RawToGuid DD8386EE09231A43B7731880CCAD6B87

Guid
----
ee8683dd-2309-431a-b773-1880ccad6b87


PS D:\SANRAL\NRA2>
```

In both cases I output a single object, not a list, and in both cases the object is easily represented by a simple string. Why do I get tabular output when I return a `Guid` type?

It may be worth noting that the `Convert-GuidToRaw` cmdlet, with its plain, un-formatted, string output, doesn't seem to properly write to the pipeline. Both cmdlets take one parameter, from the pipeline. I would expect this cmdlet pipeline below to output a GUID, when instead the last cmdlet in the pipeline is till looking for input:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> New-Guid | Convert-GuidToRaw | Convert-RawToGuid

cmdlet Convert-RawToGuid at command pipeline position 3
Supply values for the following parameters:
Input:
```

Why is `Convert-RawToGuid` not getting a "pipelined" string from `Convert-GuidToRaw`? Swapping the order of the pipeline as below, causes the expected behaviour:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Convert-RawToGuid F3BD9411DE8E4F4BBCACECFCED6D305D | Convert-GuidToRaw
F3BD9411DE8E4F4BBCACECFCED6D305D
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

The `Convert-RawToGuid` cmdlet looks like this:

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsData.Convert, "RawToGuid")]
public class ConvertRawToGuidCommand : System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet
{
    [Parameter(Mandatory = true, Position = 1, ValueFromPipeline = true)]
    public string Input { get; set; }

    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Input) || Input.Length != 32)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Input must be a 32 character hex string");
        }
        var guid = GuidConverter.Core.GuidConverter.FromRaw(Input);
        WriteObject(guid);
    }
}
```

The `Convert-GuidToRaw` cmdlet looks like this:

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsData.Convert, "GuidToRaw")]
public class ConvertGuidToRawCommand : System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet
{
    [Parameter(Mandatory = true, Position = 1, ValueFromPipeline = true)]
    public Guid Input { get; set; }

    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        var raw = GuidConverter.Core.GuidConverter.ToRaw(Input);
        WriteObject(raw);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code for Convert-GuidToRaw as well? I should have thought to ask for that at the same time as Convert-RawToGuid! :-S

Comment: @mclayton Have done so.

Comment: I've tried to repro the issue here with a new Visual Studio solution (C# Class Library, .Net Framework 4.7.2), adding the NuGet package ```Microsoft.PowerShell.5.1.ReferenceAssemblies``` and then just pasting your code into two new class files (except for the serialisation format - using ```Input.ToString()``` and ```new Guid(this.Input)``` to convert values). Then, in PowerShell ```Import-Module ".\MyCmdlet.dll"; New-Guid | Convert-GuidToRaw | Convert-RawToGuid``` and it *just works* :-S. Could you see if your project is any different to my repro, and maybe try my steps yourself?

Comment: @mclayton For which Cmdlet did you use `Input.ToString()` and new `Guid(this.Input)`? Nowhere can the input string be converted straight to a `Guid` - it must be parsed.

Comment: I've added a Part 2 to my answer that explains the above comment in more detail than 600 characters can :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Part 1**

> In both cases I output a single object, not a list, and in both cases the object is easily represented by a simple string. Why do I get tabular output when I return a Guid type?

When a command in an interactive session returns an unassigned value, PowerShell passes it to a default [Format Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/using-format-commands-to-change-output-view?view=powershell-5.1) to generate the text before it's written to the console. PowerShell is pre-configured with a bunch of Format Commands for some specific types, and [System.Guid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid?view=netframework-4.8) is one of those types.

For example:

```bsh
PS> [Guid]::NewGuid()

Guid
----
ee737b6f-7f68-4015-8841-1278b37a6420
```

The default formatters for various types are configured in *.Format.ps1xml files in PowerShell 5.1, and are baked into the source code from PowerShell 6 onwards as per [About Format.ps1xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml?view=powershell-7.x)

In PowerShell 5.1, the default formatter configuration for System.Guid can be found in `$PSHOME\DotNetTypes.format.ps1xml` and looks like this:

```
<View>
  <Name>System.Guid</Name>
  <ViewSelectedBy>
    <TypeName>System.Guid</TypeName>
  </ViewSelectedBy>
  <TableControl>
    <TableRowEntries>
      <TableRowEntry>
        <TableColumnItems>
          <TableColumnItem>
            <PropertyName>Guid</PropertyName>
          </TableColumnItem>
        </TableColumnItems>
      </TableRowEntry>
    </TableRowEntries>
  </TableControl>
</View>
```

so you get a table with a single column that contains the `Guid` property.

You get exactly the same result if you do this:

```bsh
PS> [Guid]::NewGuid() | Format-Table -Property "Guid"

Guid
----
ee737b6f-7f68-4015-8841-1278b37a6420
```

and if you want to capture the result of the *default* formatting command into a string variable (e.g. to write to a log file) you can do this:

```bsh
PS> $text = [Guid]::NewGuid() | Out-String
PS> $text

Guid
----
ee737b6f-7f68-4015-8841-1278b37a6420
```

**Part 2**

> Why is Convert-RawToGuid not getting a "pipelined" string from Convert-GuidToRaw? Swapping the order of the pipeline as below, causes the expected behaviour:

I'm not able to reproduce your issue, but the following works for me (with the caveat that I couldn't find a library with the the class `GuidConverter.Core.GuidConverter` so I'm assuming it's a private implementation and I'm using the default string fomat instead - e.g. : "024673b5-9c65-447a-be87-dae5f11f5142"). You could try this locally and see if you get the same result or the issue you reported, and go from there...

- Create a new C# Class Library solution using .Net Framework 4.7.2 in Visual Studio
- Add a reference to the Microsoft.PowerShell.5.1.ReferenceAssemblies NuGet package
- Add the code below into a new class file and build the project:

```cs
using System;
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace MyCmdlet
{

    [Cmdlet(VerbsData.Convert, "RawToGuid")]
    public class ConvertRawToGuidCommand : Cmdlet
    {
        [Parameter(Mandatory = true, Position = 1, ValueFromPipeline = true)]
        public string Input { get; set; }
        protected override void ProcessRecord()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Input) || this.Input.Length != 36)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Input must be a 36 character hex string");
            }
            var guid = new Guid(this.Input);
            WriteObject(guid);
        }
    }

    [Cmdlet(VerbsData.Convert, "GuidToRaw")]
    public class ConvertGuidToRawCommand : Cmdlet
    {
        [Parameter(Mandatory = true, Position = 1, ValueFromPipeline = true)]
        public Guid Input { get; set; }
        protected override void ProcessRecord()
        {
            var raw = this.Input.ToString();
            WriteObject(raw);
        }
    }

}
```

If I build this code I can reference it from PowerShell and the following code works:

```
PS> Import-Module ".\MyCmdlet.dll"
PS> New-Guid | Convert-GuidToRaw | Convert-RawToGuid

Guid
----
15591624-44c9-4c55-acd7-22b7a2d0bee0
```

Comment: Thanks for all the info on formatting. I have added my implementation of `Convert-RawToGuid` to the question. It is C# and not PowerShell script.

Comment: It's interesting that you use a .NET invocation to get a new GUID, where I have a `New-Guid` cmdlet available, that seems build in.

Comment: @ProfK - re [Guid]::NewGuid - I come from a C# background - I tend to drop down to the .Net classes by default :-).

Comment: I'm also from a long C# background, but I always forget how easy it is to use the .Net classes in PS. Thanks for a reminder.